# Can data from remote MySQL Database be imported into DataGridView in Windows Form Apps using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to import data from a remote MySql Workbench Database into a datagridview in windows form apps using c# but the data won't display. If I try importing data from a local database its no problem but since it's remote the data won't display.

If I write code that prints the data to the console all the data displays so my question is, would I have to create my own custom 'datagridview' from scratch?

I've also seen SQL Server Management Studio can be used. Would that be a better fit since it's a remote database?

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No need to create custom gridview, you need to identify the problem first, check SQL response has data or not, if you already have, please put some code snippets to us for checking the error. There is no important where are data came from (local and remote database)

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem. Completely forgot that I disabled the function where you can connect to the SQL Database through the PORT 3306 from a public network. When I connected from the local network everything worked fine the whole time XD